# how to insert a new record if record not exist for the specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have a table with columns `date`, `shipperName`, `Shippercode` and `Volume`.
I need to get records for the entire month. for example: If I'm passing parameter `Date='04/24/2018'` - I should get the entire month's data - if any data missing for one date, it has to copy from last know record.

For example:

I have records till 04/18/2018 - I need to copy the record of 04/18/2018 to 
 04/19/2018 - 04/30/3028. 
How can I do this in SQL store procedure?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: I'm expecting solution in MS SQL 2014

Comment: You tagged your request with Oracle, but you want a solution for Microsoft SQL Server???

Comment: sorry for the trouble. i corrected

Comment: Do you want to insert the records or select them? It's not quite clear.

Comment: It will be so much easier if you can show us a sample table & expected outcome.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive query to get the desired dates on-the-fly. Then outer apply the existing records:

```
with dates(date) as
(
  select cast('20180301' as date)
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, date) from dates where date < getdate()
)
select * 
from dates
outer apply
(
  select top(1) *
  from mytable m
  where m.date <= dates.date
  order by m.date desc
) shippers
order by dates.date;
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/USQF3805

Comment: Recursive queries aren't the best performers, I would recommend using a Numbers table and date conversion instead.

Comment: @Anthony Hancock: Why fight performance issues that might never occur? How many days do you actually expect we are going to show? A million? It's more likely that we talk about tens or hundreds here. No big deal.

Comment: I agree that in this instance the recursive option probably won't make a big performance difference either way. But if you develop bad habits with simple solutions, then they come back to bite you in the more complex ones.